# How to add RFC 8288 HTTP link header to a response

Tags: asp.net-core, hateoas

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project and I'd like to implement HATEOAS following the [Web Linking specification (RFC 8288)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288).

After browsing through Microsoft's references I was left with the impression that the best option available is to append the `Link` header as a custom header with calls to `this.Response.Headers.Add()`, which suggests that it's up to the developer to handle how links are encoded according to RFC8288.

As the task of adding HTTP link headers according to RFC8288 appears to be very common, does anyone know if there is any alternative to rolling our own solution?

Comment: Frankly, I know of no actual implementation of HATEOAS in any framework or client. The reason mostly boils down to it's virtually impossible to standardize, so it just make more sense for each API/client combination to implement it independently on their own. That said, the most common approach is via the response body, i.e. in the serialized JSON/XML/whatever response. Headers would be highly atypical.

Comment: IIRC currently there is a mix of about half a dozen standards and specifications for HATEOAS, featuring specs such as HAL and JSON-LD. Nevertheless, my question was regarding how to set the Link headers in compliance with RFC 8288 without having to reinvent the wheel.